# How to add and update Kivy progressbar during photo process

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

My project: App for taking photos from USB cams (cca 5 photos) and i need to add progressbar during photo process (each photo take real cca 1 second).
Bellow is working example of simplified version of app.

After a lot of hours googling still i don't know how can i add kivy progressbar during photo process. A goal is progressbar which will by updated after every photo (ex. 20% -> 40% -> 60% -> 80% -> 100%).

**Working example**:

Main requirements:

```
kivy, numpy, opencv-python
```

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import (NumericProperty, StringProperty)

import cv2
import numpy as np
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial


kv = '''
<PhotoProgressBar>:

    padding: "30dp"
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: root.text_value
        halign: "center"

    ProgressBar:
        value: root.number_value
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.7}


<MainScreen>:
    id: main_screen
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        id: content_area

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.2
        Button:
            on_release: root.start_photo_process()
            text: 'Take Photos'
'''
class PhotoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return MainScreen()


class PhotoProgressBar(BoxLayout):
    number_value = NumericProperty(0)
    text_value = StringProperty('default text')


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.photo_progressbar = PhotoProgressBar(
            number_value=25,
            text_value='Updated text'
        )

        # only example, i need insert progressbar before photo process
        self.insert_progressbar()

    cam_index = 0   # set available cam index (notebook webcam usually 0 or 2)
    photo_count = 5

    def start_photo_process(self, *args):
        self.ids.content_area.clear_widgets(
            self.ids.content_area.children)

        self.take_photo()

    def take_photo(self):
        print('Take photo')
        frames_list = []

        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam_index)

        cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)
        cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1)

        cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(
            'M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
        # Why isn't progressbar inserted? Call is very simmilar to
        # function load_and_show_photo()
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.insert_progressbar))

        for photo_shot in range(self.photo_count):

            success, frame = cam.read()

            if success:

                # how to update progressbar value from this for statement?
                self.photo_progressbar.number_value = str(photo_shot)
                self.photo_progressbar.text_value = str(photo_shot)

                border_color = [255, 255, 255]
                frame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
                                frame,
                                10,     # top
                                10,     # bottom
                                10,     # left
                                10,     # right
                                cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                                value=border_color
                            )

                frames_list.append(frame)
            else:
                print('#### PHOTO ERROR ####')

        frame = np.concatenate(frames_list, axis=1)

        cv2.imwrite('example_photo.jpg', frame)

        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.load_and_show_photo,
                                    'example_photo.jpg'))

    def insert_progressbar(self, *args):
        if self.ids.content_area.children:
            self.ids.content_area.remove_widget(
                self.ids.content_area.children[0])
        self.ids.content_area.add_widget(self.photo_progressbar)

    def load_and_show_photo(self, filename, *args):
        self.last_photo = Image(source=filename)
        self.last_photo.remove_from_cache()

        if self.ids.content_area.children:
            self.ids.content_area.remove_widget(
                self.ids.content_area.children[0])
        self.ids.content_area.add_widget(self.last_photo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PhotoApp().run()
```

Other information are inserted in code as comments.

Thank you for any useful information.

Comment: spawn a thread. do the things. update progress bar in whatever mechanism is provided by kivy. if this were Qt, you'd have to emit a signal for the progress bar to catch.